# Is it possible to grid bootstrap vertically?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

It seems that bootstrap can only produce horizontal grid systems which is making it hard for me to try develop a project. Here's what I am trying to do:

My page is divided into 4 sections, the leftside height of each blocks are different to the height of the rightside blocks.

I want to make the leftside have the same equal height while the right side has a different height each width which I can do when the grid is a horizontal system.

I want box1 and box2 to be the same height (vh-50) and then box3 to have the equal height.
my desired grid layout:
[image: output]

I've tried doing it like this but it doesn't work and look horrible.

```css
#infoBox {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 60vh;
}

#tracklistBox {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40vh;
}

#playBox {
  height: 50vh;
}

#episodesBox {
  height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
      <div id="infoBox" class="col border">
        1 of 2
      </div>
      <div id="tracklistBox" class="col border">
        2 of 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="playBox" class="col border">
        1 of 3
      </div>
      <div id="episodesBox" class="col border">
        2 of 3
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not bootstrap but you can use the grid system

```css
 .parent {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
    }

    .div1 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .div2 {
        grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 3;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .div3 {
        grid-area: 1 / 3 / 4 / 4;
        background-color: violet;
    }

    .div4 {
        grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4;
        background-color: greenyellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="div3">Box 3</div>
    <div class="div4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in bootstrap?

Comment: sorry better question, is it possible to make responsive?